# Edit (advanced) customs fields on page template

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, page-template

OK I'm freaking out a little bit here :) Step back.

I have to make some changes to a wordpress website (with a custom template) that I "inherited" from another guy, which developed it in 2015 and then moved to better and brighter roads.

Said website uses advanced custom fields (pro). I need to change some text / images in the homepage. Such text and images are stored in two custom fields. These two custom fields have a rule that say "show this field group if Page Template is equal to Home Page". However, i cannot find this "home page" Page Template ANYWHERE. There's a "template" menu item in the back-end with a "page" subitem, which however is empty.

If there are these custom fields, and if someone filled them in with images and texts, there should be somewhere in the back end the possibility to change them, right? But where? What am I missing?

Apologies if the question is basic or unclear!

Comment: With WordPress it's possible to use `is_home()` as a condition in other templates, like the header.php as an example - so that may have been what the original dev meant rather than a full template like `home-page.php` or whatever.  Look through any and all templates that may be displaying the fields in question and check for any `is_home()` conditions.  Keep an eye out for `is_frontpage()` as well.

Comment: You could also look through the database to find the fields and (depending on how complex they are) you might be able to change things there.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciated. @WebElaine: i have identified the file home-template.php, which indeed shows the fields that i wish to change. However, the field variable is written as `$pblText = get_field('_pbl_box_text');` and here i'm stuck, cause i don't know where this "get _field" function is getting the information from... And i assume that at some point this field was supposed to be changed from the back-end of wordpress... so it should be possible to do this again, right?

Comment: It may have been hooked up at one point and removed, or maybe the original developer never actually hooked things up. Sometimes a client will ask for one thing at first (editable X and Y) and later in the project say something like "You know, I don't think we'll ever change that text" so it might have been partially completed. If the site is not using a static Page for the front page, I would search for an ACF Options Page that was added somewhere else in wp-admin.